# Python requests загрузка файла который создаётся динамически по запросу

Tags: python, curl, requests, wget

Имеется ссылка вида ...get_catalog/?type=csv По клику, в течение 5-10 сек формируется файл, который браузер предлагает сохранить. Имя файла в Response Header появляется не сразу и файл в заголовке обозначен как content-disposition: attachment; filename=catalog_10-03-2020_00-09.csv

Попытки сохранить файл с помощью кода

```
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + '/get_catalog/?type=csv', stream=True)
catalog_save_path = BASE_SAVE_PATH / 'catalog.csv'
with open(str(catalog_save_path.absolute()), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Не приносят успеха. Вместо файла сохраняется html-страница. Пробовал

```
os.system(f'wget --content-disposition  {BASE_URL + "/get_catalog/?type=csv"}')
```

и

```
os.system(f'curl -O -J -L  {BASE_URL + "/get_catalog/?type=csv"}')
```

Результат аналогичный. Есть идеи как можно сделать так, чтобы сохранялся именно файл?

Comment: А что в этой html странице?

Comment: Да, счас пересмотрел html код, сохраняется страница, как будто, я не прошел авторизацию. Хотя странно. На запрос авторизации выдавался код 200. Т.е. по идее всё должно быть с этим нормально.

Comment: Я в питоне он силен, но результат этой авторизации вы куда-то сохранили?

Comment: Результаты я никуда не сохранял. Для этого есть библиотека, объекты которой должны хранить всю нужную информацию. Авторизовался так >>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>

Comment: Вот документация на библиотеку https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/authentication/

Comment: Кажется вы не понимаете как работает Basic Auth. Вы должны передавать его в *каждом* запросе